# Dividing in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

can anyone explain to me why this query returns 0.000?

```
SELECT CAST(20/1024 AS NUMERIC(10,3))
```

I am just trying to do a simple conversion of MB to GB

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing an integer division first and then convert the result. The integer division results in 0. Converting 0 to `NUMERIC(10,3)` results in `0.000`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18998)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 20/1024;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18998/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
------------
|        0 |
```

To get a non-integer-division you need to convert at least on of the two numbers involved to something other than an integer. In the case of number literals you can just add a `.` after the digits:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT 20./1024;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18998/1)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
------------
| 0.019531 |
```

In the case of variables or columns you need to convert one of them using `CAST` or `CONVERT`:

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT 20/CAST(1024 AS NUMERIC(10,3));
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18998/2)**:

```
|   COLUMN_0 |
--------------
| 0.01953125 |
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I figured it out as above but you have shown me something I didn't know here.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the divide operator to do a integer division.

Quoting the [Divide arithmetic operator documentation from Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx):

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is
>   an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

To get a result with a decimal part, you should first convert one of the operands to a different data type – either `FLOAT` or `NUMERIC` work just fine.

For example ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19008)):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(20 AS FLOAT) / 1024 AS NUMERIC(10,3))
```

Returns `0.02`.

Comment: Avoid the use of `FLOAT` and `REAL` unless that is explicitly what you want, or you will fall into traps due to floating point approximations. See http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/08/12/floating_point_approximation/ and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (amongst other references) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I fixed it already, its because I had to cast each integer not the whole thing.  So this worked:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(20 AS DECIMAL(2,0))/CAST(1024 AS DECIMAL(4,0)) AS DECIMAL(10,3))
```